# Looking for a package in Alpine linux for installing numpy

Tags: numpy, alpine-linux

I've been searching all over the internet to find numpy package for the Alpine linux, did not find any, so Ii tried to install it from the source by cloning git, faced with numerous problems! so it came to my mind to ask the community about whether there is any package in Alpine linux distro in order to install numpy as part of it?!

Comment: so using `pip` is not an option for you?

Comment: Thank you, did not came to my mind, and it is resolved now,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so as it is mentioned in comments for the first post, the steps are as follows:

```
apk add --update py-pip
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find `py-numpy` by adding the following line to `/etc/apk/repositories`

```
@testing http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing
```

and then calling the apk add specifying the testing repo

```
apk add --update py-numpy@testing
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to Looking for a package in Alpine linux for installing numpy

If you can't find the package with command `apk search numpy`, then try this:

login https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents

search the key word: `numpy%`

#### explain:

`numpy%` - % is used as wildcard

So you will get several packages, `py-numpy` and `py-numpy-dev` should be the packages you are looking for.

> It is in testing Repository, so you need install it with py-numpy@testing

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy//numpyconfig.h    py-numpy-dev    testing x86_64
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils//numpy_distribution.py py-numpy    testing x86_64
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils//numpy_distribution.pyc    py-numpy    testing x86_64
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages//numpy-1.9.2-py2.7.egg-info    py-numpy    testing x86_64
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave//numpy_scalar_spec.py  py-scipy    testing x86_64
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/weave//numpy_scalar_spec.pyc py-scipy    testing x86_64
```

Comment: Currently, it seems one uses `*` as a wildcard in these searches, not `%`.

Answer (score 0):

Alpine pacakge `py-numpy` is included in Alpine 3.5 and newer (for example, see the [py-numpy package for Alpine 3.6 on x86](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.6/community/x86/py-numpy)). Install it like any other package with:

```
apk add py-numpy
```