# PyCrypto for Python3 in Alpine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycrypto, alpine-linux

Is there a package for Alpine which allows me to install PyCrypto for Python 3?

After encountering problems with `pip3 install pycrypto`, I stumbled upon this post which explains [how to install numpy in Alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279307/looking-for-a-package-in-alpine-linux-for-installing-numpy) using `apk add py-numpy@testing`. PyCrypto can also be installed for Python2.7 using `apk add py-crypto`. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to call pycrypto for Python3 or even if this package exists.

As an alternative solution, I tried to install the C compiler gcc using `apk add gcc` so that the setup tools in `pip3 install pycrypto` can compile. But, when I run that command with gcc already, it throws a fatal error:

```
...
running build_ext
running build_configure
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/pip-build-2TivSm/pycrypto':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
...
```

Is there no way to compile Python3 modules inside Alpine?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
apk add gcc g++ make libffi-dev openssl-dev
```

Then do your pip install.

Comment: Great! That was the trick. Thanks. However, I also needed to install python3-dev as well using this:  `apk add python3-dev build-base --update-cache`

Comment: Your command worked perfectly for compiling `pycryptodome` in `alpine` when I needed to use it for a Docker project.  +1.

Answer (score 4):

> *configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables*

In alpine Install their SDK.

For any compiling stuff in Alpine, make sure you have these packages.

**alpine-sdk autoconf automake libtool**

Install it ***apk add --no-cache alpine-sdk autoconf automake libtool***

Answer (score -3):

PyCrypto seems to have problems with python 3, i had a lot of struggle with that. If you are using Windows, this is the solution that worked for me:

- Install Visual Studio 2015 with Visual C++ (VS Version 2015 only works if you are using python 3.5+. If you are using 3.4, i think the correct version was VS2010. For earlier versions i am not really sure which version to choose but you can find information about that on the internet)
- Download the [pycrypto source](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/). Currently the stable release is pycrypto-2.6.1. Use this one and not the experimental version below.
- Extract the archive
- Edit the file `lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/nt.py` and replace `import winrandom` with `from Crypto.Random.OSRNG import winrandom`.
- Run the following from cmd `python setup.py build -c msvc python setup.py install python setup.py test`
- If the test gets you some errors, you might get away with it anyways.

Instructions taken from my [github project](https://github.com/instantshare/instantshare/tree/dev) (dev branch).

Comment: The question is for Alpine linux, not for windows.